# How to recache a page from a management command?

Tags: django, caching

I've got an problem with a `sitemaps.xml` taking so long to run that the search engines timeout.  There is no memcached installed so I've quickly added a FileBasedCache which happily solves the immediate problem, excepting that first request per cache life.

The sitemap changes once a week and that event is invoked by a cron job which calls a management command which loads new data.  So the immediate idea is to extend the cache life to a week and force a flush and reload of the cache whenever the cronjob/management command runs.

But how might one do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't seem to be caching elsewhere on the site for the time being the following should clear the entire cache:

```
import urllib2
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.cache import cache

sys.stdout.write('Rebuilding sitemap\n')
cache.clear()
sitemap = urllib2.urlopen('http://'+settings.HOST_DOMAIN+reverse('sitemap'))
sitemap.read()
```

I would then use urllib2 to send a request to yoursite/sitemaps.xml which should recache the new page.